# __init__.txt in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have the following structure:

```
test_init
|__________resources
|          |__________ keywords.robot
|__________tests
           |__________ __init__.txt
           |__________ TestInit.robot
```

The keywords.robot contains:

```
*** Keywords ***
Keyword for init
   Log  init
```

The __init__.txt contains:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  This is from init file
Resource  ${EXECDIR}/resources/keywords.robot
```

The TestInit.robot contains:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Testing the Init
   Log  Vimal
   Keyword for init
```

And from command line in the test_init directory, if I execute as follows:

```
> pybot tests
```

I get the error saying that:

```
No keyword with name 'Keyword for init' found
```

I was thinking, the initialization file imports the resource file as well. But the init file is recognized for the documentation and I get that in my report.

I'm bit confused on the usage of initialization file, kindly help me to understand it much better.

Answer (score 5):

The use of init file is to manage setup, teardown and tags on your whole folder/suite (and subfolders).

Init files can **not** be used to import resources (they have to be loaded in the file you use them).

Documentation has been made more clear since 2.8.7: see the [Initialization Files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.8.7/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files) section of the user guide.

Comment: But in the documentation, they say "The main usage for initialization files is specifying test suite related settings similarly as in test case files, but setting some test case related settings is also possible. Variables and keywords created or imported in initialization files are not available in the lower level test suites, __but resource files can be used if there is a need to share them.__". Also, in the example, they shown like importing a library. I don't see both are possible.

Comment: what this sentence means (maybe not clearly enough) is that resources/libraries can be *used* in __init__ files, which allows you to use keywords from these resources/library within the init file. But it does not imply that those same keyword will be available in the other files/suites.

Comment: I'm also confused on this sentence. As this statement implies, the init file should allow the resource files to be imported.

Comment: I agree documentation isn't exactly clear. What it tries to say is that if you want to share keywords/variables, you can use a resource file and import it in your init files and test case files. Keywords/variables in init files are never automatically available for lower level suites. Please submit an issue here about bad documentation and we'll improve it: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues

Comment: This was fixed by https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/commit/c0184fcd908251b719707c8b18bf7b8c1193cb2e