# Use common Suite setup and Suite teardown for several test suites in a nested folder structure robot framewrok

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm new to **Robot** framework and trying to better understand the concepts and usage in *Suite Setup* and *Suite Teardown* when the test's folder structure is not "flat". After a long search on the web, the [Robot framework user guide - executing tests section](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-execution) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33787384/1971003) which is similar but not exactly my situation, I still did not find any solution, so here we go.

My project now contains the following files:

`_init__.robot` that contains the `Suite Setup` & `Suite Teardown` "definitions", as follows:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   /path/to/some/python/file.py
Suite Setup  myCustomSuiteSetup
Suite Teardown  myCustomSuiteTeardown

*** Keywords ***
myCustomSuiteSetup
    ${ret_code} =  run keyword MySuiteSetupKeyword
    should be eqaul as integers ${ret_code} 0

myCustomSuiteTeardown
    ${ret_code} =  run keyword MySuiteTeardownKeyword
    should be eqaul as integers ${ret_code} 0
```

Where `myCustomSuiteTeardown` and `MySuiteTeardownKeyword` are keywords "linked" to some Python functions in the file `/path/to/some/python/file.py`.

The 4 suite files in my project are **currently** arranged like so:

```
|--tests
|----suite_1.robot
|----suite_2.robot 
|----suite_3.robot
|----suite_4.robot
|----__init__.robot
```

Now, the purpose (and usage) of the `Suite Setup` & `Suite Teardown` is that the `Suite Setup` will run at the beginning of the run of the ENTIRE `tests` folder, i.e.- **before** the **first** test case of the **first** suite, which in this case is `suite_1.robot` and the `Suite Teardown` will run **after** the **last** test case of the **last** suite, which in this case it is `suite_4.robot`.

For this to happen, I simply invoke all the suites as follows (from within one folder "above" the `tests` folder):

`robot tests`

So far so good.

Now my question is as follows: Actually I wish to "re-arrange" the folder's structure of the test files, like so:

```
|--tests
|----testGroup1
|--------suite_1.robot
|--------suite_2.robot 
|----testGroup2
|--------suite_3.robot
|--------suite_4.robot
|--__init__.robot    <----- Where the __init__.robot file should be placed now ?
```

Meaning, to "gather" test suites to sub-folders, nevertheless, I still wish to keep the usage of the `Suite Setup` & `Suite Teardown` as before,i.e.- upon invocation of every possible subset of the test suites under the "root" folder `tests`, `Suite Setup` & `Suite Teardown` MUST be the first and last (respectively) "steps" to be executed, meaning, for example, let say I wish to run `suite_3.robot` & `suite_4.robot`, then now, `Suite Setup` should be called before the first test case in `suite_3.robot` and `Suite Teardown` should be called after the last test case in the `suite_4.robot`. Also, of course, I wish to keep only a **single** copy of the `__init__.robot` file - i.e. - not keep two similar copies of the `__init__.robot` in each subfolder, `testGroup1` & `testGroup2`. When I did this, it worked, but this is not the (proper) way I wish to do that.

So my questions are:

1. Where do I need to place the `__init__.robot` file?
2. In case I wish to run,for instance, only the two test suites within `testGroup2` (i.e.- `suite_3.robot` & `suite_4.robot`), what command do I need to use?

Of course, in case it is not the "correct" way (approach) to achieve my objectives (single and unified `Suite Setup` & `Suite Teardown` for every test suites subset) - please advice how should it be done.

**Note:** I'm using Robot framework 3.1.2 (Python 3.5.2 on Linux)

Comment: A similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610579/init-txt-in-robot-framework

Answer (score 2):

Your placement of the initialization file in the `tests` folder that contains both `testGroup1` and `testGroup2` is correct. This way, if you run at least one test that's somewhere in `tests` or within a sub folder of it, the Suite Setup will run before all such tests and Suite Teardown afterwards.

To force the Suite Setup and Suite Teardown to run, you must keep the parent folder (`tests`) as the folder you run. It is good practice to always run the folder that contains all of your tests. That way, you don't miss any suite setups or teardowns by mistake.

To then run **only** select tests, use the options `--include` or `--exclude` for tags, or `--suite` or `--test`.

In your example, you would run the following:

`robot --suite suite_3 --suite suite_4 tests`, to run only suite_3 and suite_4

Or, you can use fully qualified suite names:

`robot --suite tests.testGroup2.suite_3 --suite tests.testGroup2.suite_4 tests`

Comment: Hudecek - One more question please: If I wish to use argument file to invoke, for example, only `suite_3` "wrapped" as usual with the `SuiteSetup` & `SuiteTeardown` how do I compose it ?

Comment: @GuyAvraham You can put `--suite` on the first line, `suite_3` on the second line and `tests` on the third line: Robot treats a newline as an argument separator in an argument file.